# Sudden Slow Reports

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs

we have reports on our report server that are running slow all of a sudden. They were working fine and then all of a sudden over the weekend they started to process incredibly slow. It appears that only the complex queries are slow, some simple reports are either running fine or run so quick that a short lag isn't noticeable.

We've tried rebooting the server and that did not help us at all. I was wondering (being very new to database administration, and while just passing my 70-461 have not dived much into this) if there was anything I can run or any DMVs I can query to try and find the root cause of this. In our small company we don't have a strait DBA, so none of us at the moment have seasoned knowledge of SQL Server (at least as of yet) that can help us troublshoot this issue.

Comment: Can you identify reports on certain tables as being slow? Have you ruled out hardware fault such as a degraded RAID volume?

Comment: And the $64K question: what changed on the weekend?

Comment: Run [sp_whoisactive](http://sqlblog.com/files/folders/beta/entry42453.aspx).

Comment: Check if there is any blocking while running those "issue" reports. Also, try running the query of that report VIA SSMS and see how fast you get the result. Moreover, include actual execution plan while executing the query of the top consuming one, and see what highlights the issue. Has re-indexing been done, and stats been updated?

Answer (score 1):

One good source for the data is plan cache, and you can find top cpu or logical reads by querying dm_exec_query_stats DMV, for example with something like this:

```
select top 100
SUBSTRING(t.text, (s.statement_start_offset/2)+1,
((CASE s.statement_end_offset
WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(t.text)
ELSE s.statement_end_offset
END - s.statement_start_offset)/2) + 1) as statement_text,
t.text,
s.total_logical_reads, s.total_logical_reads / s.execution_count as avg_logical_reads,
s.total_worker_time, s.total_worker_time / s.execution_count as avg_worker_time,
s.execution_count,
creation_time,
last_execution_time
--,cast(p.query_plan as xml) as query_plan
from sys.dm_exec_query_stats s
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text (sql_handle) t
--cross apply sys.dm_exec_text_query_plan (plan_handle, statement_start_offset, statement_end_offset) p
order by s.total_worker_time desc
```

The statistics are always the total amount from creation_time onwards for each of the statements, and execution count tells how many times it has been executed. The commented out parts are for showing the plans if you need them too. The statistics is only for those plans that still exist in the cache.

Comment: And there's also a lot more columns in dm_exec_query_stats that might interest you